# AWS Cloudformation: Tagging block device from auto-scaling launch configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, tagging, block-device

I have created an autoscaling group and its launch configuration via Cloudformation template.

The Autoscaling group has only one tag called 'name'.
There is a block device mapping for the ec2 instances in the launch configuration as below:

```
ASGLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    DependsOn: CloudwatchConfigSsm
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref PresentationAMIId
      InstanceType: !Ref PresentationInstanceType
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 20
            VolumeType: gp2
            Encrypted: true
```

But the problem is the tag called 'name' that is defined in the associated autoscaling group is not propagated to the created EBS volume.
The tag definition in the autoscaling group is below:

```
Tags:
        - Key: 'Name'
          Value: !Sub 'presentation-server-${Env}'
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
```

Further, I need to add some other important tags.
How I can achieve this?

### Update:

I created the below launch template:

```
ASGLaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    DependsOn: CloudwatchConfigSsm
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: !Sub 'ec2-launch-template-${Region}-${Env}'
      TagSpecifications:
        - ResourceType: instance
          Tags:
          - Key: System
            Value: 'xxx'
          - Key: Env
            Value: !Sub '${Env}'
          - Key: EnvNumber
            Value: '01'
          - Key: Country
            Value: !Sub '${Region}'
          - Key: Company
            Value: 'xxx'
          - Key: Global
            Value: 'all'
          - Key: CostCenter
            Value: 'xxxx'
          - Key: 'Name'
            Value: !Sub 'presentation-server-${Env}'
        - ResourceType: volume
          Tags:
          - Key: 'Name'
            Value: !Sub 'presentation-server-ebs-volume-${Env}'
          - Key: System
            Value: 'xxx'
          - Key: Env
            Value: !Sub '${Env}'
          - Key: EnvNumber
            Value: '01'
          - Key: Country
            Value: !Sub '${Region}'
          - Key: Company
            Value: 'xxx'
          - Key: Global
            Value: 'all'
          - Key: CostCenter
            Value: 'xxxx'
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: !Ref PresentationAMIId
        InstanceType: !Ref PresentationInstanceType
        NetworkInterfaces:
          - AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: 20
              VolumeType: gp2
              Encrypted: true
```

Got below error while updating the stack:

> You can specify only one TagSpecification parameter in the request.
> Ensure that the request includes only one TagSpecification parameter
> and try again.

Comment: Modified my template according to your suggestion. I will update the stack today and notify you here. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Marcin I updated the question with the error output while updating the stack

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is your new code? You can make new question with if you want.

Comment: @Marcin Updated the question with code

Comment: I updated the answer with corrected template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
ASGLaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    DependsOn: CloudwatchConfigSsm
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: !Sub 'ec2-launch-template-${Region}-${Env}'
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: !Ref PresentationAMIId
        TagSpecifications:
          - ResourceType: instance
            Tags:
            - Key: System
              Value: 'xxx'
            - Key: Env
              Value: !Sub '${Env}'
            - Key: EnvNumber
              Value: '01'
            - Key: Country
              Value: !Sub '${Region}'
            - Key: Company
              Value: 'xxx'
            - Key: Global
              Value: 'all'
            - Key: CostCenter
              Value: 'xxxx'
            - Key: 'Name'
              Value: !Sub 'presentation-server-${Env}'
          - ResourceType: volume
            Tags:
            - Key: 'Name'
              Value: !Sub 'presentation-server-ebs-volume-${Env}'
            - Key: System
              Value: 'xxx'
            - Key: Env
              Value: !Sub '${Env}'
            - Key: EnvNumber
              Value: '01'
            - Key: Country
              Value: !Sub '${Region}'
            - Key: Company
              Value: 'xxx'
            - Key: Global
              Value: 'all'
            - Key: CostCenter
              Value: 'xxxx'        
        InstanceType: !Ref PresentationInstanceType
        NetworkInterfaces:
          - AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: 20
              VolumeType: gp2
              Encrypted: true
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and let you know soon

Comment: @MahbubRahman How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I understood from your answer above what mistake I made in the template. The TagSpecifications were not placed in the correct place. I made the correction but did not update my stack yet. I will surely let you know once I am done.

Comment: @MahbubRahman Any good news?

Comment: @kaissun Yes, it is working

Comment: You can use Marcin's answer